# Org-export: How to filter table of contents entities

Tags: org-mode, org-export

This is a follow-up question from this: [Replace \LaTeX command in HTML export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64025/org-mode-export-to-html-filter-replace-latex-commands)

Consider following org-mode file:

```
* Text about exporting from org-mode to \LaTeX

text

* Text about exporting from org-mode to HTML

another text
```

If I export this file to HTML and also use filter to replace "\LaTeX" in heading with simple "LaTeX", I end up with table of contents entries that still contain "\LaTeX" as a string, instead of the replacement "LaTeX."

I should also add that I am using Doom Emacs and I am running Emacs in non-interactive session through `makefile` (I am doing multiple exports to multiple export formats).

Looking to org-manual about TOC, I could use property `ALT_TITLE` ([org TOC](https://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-Contents.html)), but because I am exporting also to LaTeX, that would mean I would lost formatting in there.

I reused filter fom linked question:

```
(require 'ox)
(require 'ox-html)

(defun my-latex-filter-example (text backend info)
  "Replace \LaTeX with \"LaTeX\" in HTML output."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\LaTeX" "LaTeX" text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-link-functions
             'my-latex-filter-example)
```

According to optons listed in manual: [Advanced Export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html) I have also tryied `plain-text` and `options` `org-export-filter-functions`, but none were able to remove string "\LaTeX" from HTML table of contents.

Is there a way to target with filter functions links generated by TOC in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro that expands differently in the two cases:

```
#+MACRO: latex @@latex:\LaTeX@@ @@html:LaTeX@@

* Something about {{{latex}}}
  {{{latex}}} is cool.
```

Check out the section in the manual on macros with `C-h i g (org)macro` and the various sections on quoting constructs, e.g. `C-h i g (org)quoting latex` for latex and similar ones for the other exporters.